# Subversion deployment onto Windows Server 2003 environment

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I recently asked a question on which Subversion to use and have done with VisualSVN Server, however after installing it and updating folder permissions I now get the following issues:

1) When logged into the server and browsing the 'Repositories' in VisualSVN Server all items return the following error:

***'Can't open file C:\inetpub\website\format: The system cannot find the file specified'***

2) Which is related is when browing via HTTPS to the server and trying to open one of the sites I get the following error:

***This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
< D:error >
< C:error / >
< m:human-readable errcode="720002" > Could not open the requested SVN filesystem < / m:human-readable >
< / D: error >***

Comment: Issue resolved. Had to use the create command within VisualSVN Server.